# encrypt database connect string for azure website

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, azure, encryption

seems there is no good way to encrypt database connect string for azure website (not cloud service), i already view the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22823930/encrypt-database-connection-string-in-azure-websites)
but, i can't store the database first entity framework connect string in the azure website setting, which will get below error, anyone knows how to make data base connect string secure in azure website using database first entity framework?

System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.UnintentionalCodeFirstException: The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First development.  This will not work correctly. To fix this problem do not remove the line of code that throws this exception. If you wish to use Database First or Model First, then make sure that the Entity Framework connection string is included in the app.config or web.config of the start-up project. If you are creating your own DbConnection, then make sure that it is an EntityConnection and not some other type of DbConnection, and that you pass it to one of the base DbContext constructors that take a DbConnection. To learn more about Code First, Database First, and Model First see the Entity Framework documentation here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394715

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to include the connection string in the web.config for your site. You can manage the connection string in your azure account at:

```
App Services>[your_app_name]>Settings>Application settings
```

Under `Connection strings` section, you can set the key/value pair which is the  connection name and the db connection string.

After you set those values, in the screen, the connection string will be hidden for display.

Comment: thank you Allan, i already tried to do that, above error occured if i add connect string in azure website setting. i use database first entity frame, seems the connect string can only be added in web.config.

Comment: i choose "Custom" in the azure connect string setting, and it worked.